# Function called on second click of button ( not on first )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button when clicked i want it to ensure the .mo function is called, however it will only run that function on the second click.

The mealplan() function is running correctly

HTML

```
<button class="" id="mealbtn" onclick="mealplan()">CLICK ME</button>
```

I need both the mealplan() and .mo function to be called upon click.

```
 function mealplan(){
       // also runs on click          
      }

      Shopify.mo = function(q,ref) {
  // this is the function that I need to run uupon click, but it is only running on second click
      };

      $('#mealbtn').on('click', function(e) {
        // should call the .mo function on click 
        Shopify.mo(Shopify.queuemeals,"note");

      });
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra closing bracket. Is the $('#mealbtn').on('click') inside the mealplan function??

Comment: @chris cozzens: Have you corrected the code in the question as well? Don't do that, it will help fellow users find any mistakes that they might have made. Please revert it back to the way the question was answered if possible.

Comment: @NikhilGirraj no correct made, see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery `on('click')` method only happens when the button is clicked.
Your code is suggesting that when the button is clicked, we initialize the button's click method.

To fix it, move your jQuery event to a function that runs when the page loads:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#mealbtn').on('click', function(e) {
        // should call the .mo function on click 
        Shopify.mo(Shopify.queuemeals,"note");
      });
});
```